# Unity 2D Not detecting when touching object with tag obstacle

Tags: c#, flappy-bird-clone, unity2.0

I am making a game similar to flappy bird I am currently following this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihvBiJ1oC9U&t=3014s) and I'm stuck near the end I have been searching for 4hours and can't find a solution here's the code

Game Manager:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int score;

    public void GameOver()
    {
        Debug.Log("Game Over!");
    }

    public void IncreaseScore()
    {
        score++;
    }
}
```

player:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playermove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 direction;

    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    public float strength = 5f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            direction = Vector3.up * strength;
        }

        direction.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position += direction * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().GameOver();
        } else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Score")
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().IncreaseScore();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to detect when the player hits a sprite with a tag and 2d collider (set as a trigger)
edit: Inspector ss of trigger object

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot from your Unity editor showing the inspector of your trigger objects any of those two it will be fine.

Also you can try the CompareTag() method like this : other.CompareTag("Obstacle")

Comment: Sure check the edit on question

Comment: CompareTag() does not work :(

Comment: Your Obstacle object inspector looks ok. Are you sure the issue is the collision detection and not the "FindObjectOfType<GameManager>()". Try add some "Debug.Log()" and see if the trigger can be detected or not. Also make sure that have in your scene an empty object with the "GameManager" script attached to it.

Comment: There is an empty object with the script attached to it. I can't add a debug.log the error is 
Assets\Scripts\playermove.cs(25,45): error CS1061: 'GameManager' does not contain a definition for 'Debug' and no accessible extension method 'Debug' accepting a first argument of type 'GameManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try add "using System.Collections;" in your GameManager script and see if the error is fixed.

Comment: no? wwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: Nope :( I guess I should just quit cause I have been searching for 2 days

Comment: That's the most common thing that you will experience as a programmer. Searching for days to fix an issue

Comment: its been 4 days for me